# how i can insert data into database from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection
    ("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=HRPR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=11");

```
SqlCommand com;

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=HRPR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=11");
connStr.Open();
foreach  (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows) 
{
    com = new
    SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblExmWrittn(Cirname,publishingDate,ApplicantId,Applicantname,HighestMrk,WrittnAchievMrk) VALUES( '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); + "', '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();+ "' , '" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();+ "' ,'" + row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();+ "','" + row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();+ "' ,'" + row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();+ "','" + row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();+ "')", connStr);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connStr.Close();
}

Label1.Text = "Records inserted successfully"; 


}
```

Comment: show the table structure for tblExmWrittn

Comment: WrittnId int Unchecked
Cirname varchar(50) Checked
publishingDate datetime Checked
ApplicantId varchar(50) Checked
Applicantname varchar(50) Checked
HighestMrk varchar(50) Checked
WrittnAchievMrk varchar(50) Checked
  Unchecked

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection
    ("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=HRPR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=11");

SqlCommand com;
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=HRPR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=11");
    connStr.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows) 
    {
        com = new
        SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblExmWrittn(column1,column2....)  VALUES( '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); + "', '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();+ "' , '" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();+ "' ,'" + row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();+ "','" + row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();+ "' ,'" + row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();+ "','" + row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();+ "')", connStr);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connStr.Close();
    }

    Label1.Text = "Records inserted successfully"; 

}
```

Comment: When i build it..it show me Error 3 Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow.Cells' cannot be used like a method. F:\3.7.13\HrPayRoll\Recruitment\123t.aspx.cs 31 185 F:\3.7.13\HrPayRoll\

Comment: Try square brackets..    Cells[1]

Comment: but ...'" + g1.Cells[0].Value + "' now it show error for . value

Comment: Error 2 The name 'row' does not exist in the current context F:\3.7.13\HrPayRoll\Recruitment\123t.aspx.cs 54 139 F:\3.7.13\HrPayRoll\

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline parameters to build your SQL statement.

Use SQL parameters and separate the data access and UI layer.

You have int values, strings, datetime values in your table but are you sending all these data in correct format?  (you don't need `''` for int values parameters)

you can avoid all by using SQL parameters.

And note that you are closing the connection after first row in the loop, and newer open it again for next rows. better to close the connection at the end of the all rows.

I would create seperate method for insert record as below

```
public void InsertExamWrittn(int writtnId, string cirname, DateTime publishingDate, string applicantId, string applicantname, string highestMrk, string writtnAchievMrk)
{

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=HRPR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=11"))
    using(var cmd= con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblExmWrittn (WrittnId, Cirname, publishingDate, ApplicantId, Applicantname, HighestMrk, WrittnAchievMrk) "+
                            "VALUES (@WrittnId, @Cirname, @publishingDate, @ApplicantId, @Applicantname, @HighestMrk, @WrittnAchievMrk)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WrittnId", writtnId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cirname", cirname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publishingDate", publishingDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicantId", applicantId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Applicantname", applicantname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HighestMrk", highestMrk);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WrittnAchievMrk", writtnAchievMrk);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

from `Button2_Click` event I would call this method by giving relevant parameters for each row